# Use the Cauchy Integral Formula to evaluate the following integral: $\int \frac{e^z \,dz}{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Use the Cauchy Integral Formula to evaluate:
$$\int_\gamma \frac{e^z \, dz}{z^2+1}$$
where $\gamma$ is the circle with centre $i$ and radius $1$.

I found that the poles of the function were at $\pm i$, but I don't understand how to use this as part of the formula.
$$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [The example on Wikipedia should help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$\frac{e^z}{z^2+1}=\frac{\frac{e^z}{z+i}}{z-i},$$the answer is$$2\pi i\frac{e^i}{i+i}=\pi\bigl(\cos(1)+i\sin(1)\bigr).$$

Comment: Thanks a million! I'm assuming that you used $+i$ as $-i$ lies outside of $\gamma$?And, for arguments sake, if $\gamma$ included $\pm i$, what would you have to do then? Would it be the sum of the solutions?

Comment: I'm using the fact that $i$ is the circle with centre $i$ and radius $1$, whereas $-i$ is outside. If both were inside, I would have applied the residue theorem.